# I cannot import an Excel workbook into Azure Data Studio on my macbook

Tags: xlsx

When I am trying to import an Excel workbook into Azure Data Studio with the import wizard on my macbook, can anyone help me?

It looks like Azure does not understand the xlsx format and the preview looks like gibberish, and even when I convert to a `.csv`, the preview looks better but I always get errors and I am unable to import. It looks like it has something to do with the data types but I am not sure.

Comment: What errors? Some examples would maybe help here.

Comment: Ohh isn't there a file format difference between a PC Excel file and Mac One? Or did they consolidate it?  Azure is MS so I suspect it wants the PC version?

Comment: @SolarMike I'm still new to this so I can't really understand the errors that pop up but what I can see mostly are things like: SystemInvalidOperationException, SystemFormatException, SystemGlobalisation

Comment: @easleyfixed I specifically got azure for the MacBook and also use excel on my MacBook. I am following a tutorial online to do a portfolio project but the teacher is working on a windows PC and I am trying to figure out how to do what he's doing on my MacBook. I can provide a link to the video if you wish

Comment: Unfortunately I do MySQL stuff instead of Excel, but If the tutorial is being done by a PC,  and you are using a MAC, perhaps you can find a tutorial to do it with Mac, as it sounds like booting into a PC environment to follow the tutorial isn't possible for you?  But to reiterate what I said in my previous comment, an Excel file made on a PC and one made on a MAC are 2 different file formats, despite being able to be opened in either one.